# Create a unique constraint where one column can be null to prevent duplicate record insertion

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres 13.4, trying to create a unique constraint where a record in a cars table is unique by name and user_id. The purchased_at date starts out as NULL but can change to a value once a car is purchased. I run the following but get a syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE cars 
   ADD CONSTRAINT cars_user_id_name_purchased_at_key 
   UNIQUE (user_id, name) 
WHERE purchased_at IS NULL
```

Error:

> ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) syntax error at or near "WHERE"

What is the issue and how to fix?

Comment: Wait, so once a car is purchased you want to lift the uniqueness constraint?

Comment: I changed the names (and hence the domain model) to obscure the production system a bit; but essentially you're creating a new car by name (tied to a user though, so 2 different users could have the same car name in this system) and we didn't want to allow duplicate names. Think of "purchased_at" as doing a soft delete in the new car inventory but tied to a user.

Comment: You need a unique _index_ in order to be able to use a WHERE clause. This is not possible for a unique constraint

Comment: @Nona But can a user create another car with the same name after they soft-deleted the first?

Comment: @Bergi - yes they can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a `WHERE` clause in a constraint definition, but a partial unique index will do the trick:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON cars (user_id, name) 
WHERE purchased_at IS NULL;
```